# Build apex code locally

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm trying to configure jenkins as continuous integration server with ant migration tool, so i'm searching information in how can i build apex code from jenkins, so since now the only i've found is how to deploy the code to salesforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (currently) no local build step. Source code and other components are pushed to a target Salesforce org and the code is compiled on demand there.

So from Jenkins, you use the Ant deploy to deploy the code and run its unit tests which largely ensures that the code is correct and that all the components that the code depends on are included in the deploy (or already present in the org).

See e.g. [Setting Up Jenkins for Force.com Continuous Integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html).